# How to prevent checkbox animation after setting the value

Tags: android

On Android >= 21 (lollipop), if I change the checked status of a checkbox, it does an animation. I want to prevent it.

I tried to temporarily set the `stateListAnimator` to `null`, but this did not help. How to prevent the animation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. This helped me. Just add this after you set the checked state:

```
checkbox.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
```

I hope I could help you :)

Liam